# Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run: remote: npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Tags: heroku, npm, web-deployment, mern, web-compiler

I want to deploy the MERN project on Heroku. When I write command `git push heroku main`, then an error comes.

```
 Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
 remote: npx browserslist@latest --update-db
```

I tried following solutions but it can't help

`npx browserslist@latest --update-db`

`npm i autoprefixer@latest`

`npm i caniuse-lite browserslist@latest`

`npm i caniuse-lite@latest`

`npm --depth 9999 update`

`npm --depth 99 update caniuse-lite browserslist`